# Rigid Usage of Int in Haskell functions

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell programming and I wanted to know why I get an error

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Eq Int
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
```

when I am trying to define a function like this

```
union :: (Eq (Int)) => [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

Comment: Just remove the constraint.  `Eq Int =>` is basically meaningless - you should use constraints only with type variables.  For eample `union :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

Comment: is there a specific reason for it?

Comment: @DipeshDesai Why would you need to tell the compiler that `Int` is an instance of `Eq`? It already knows that. *Only* use type constraints in polymorphic functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type class constraints exist to restrict the types that your function works with. For example if you have the type `a -> a -> a` that's a function that needs to be able to handle any type of arguments (as long as both arguments have the same type). If you change it to `Eq a => a -> a -> a`, it now only needs to work with arguments of a type that implements `Eq`, allowing you to use `==` on the arguments.

In your case you have a function of type `[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`. That's already as restricted as it gets: The function works specifically with two arguments of type `[Int]` - no other types are allowed.

So restricting it to only those types `Int` that implement `Eq` makes no sense because `Int` is already one specific type. So the type should just be `[Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]` and you will still be allowed to use `==` because `Int` does implement `Eq`.

Answer (score 5):

You here write:

```
Eq Int => ...
```

But this is useless, we know for sure that `Int` is an instance of the `Eq` typeclass, it is redundant to state that.

Usually you only write type constraints with a type variable in it, for example:

```
union :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

would indeed require to write such type constraint. In that case we can use a `union` for *every* `a`, given that `Eq a` holds. This holds given `a ~ Int`, but with the latter we can also use it for `a ~ Char`, `a ~ Maybe Int`, etc.

The idea is that if you write `Eq a`, you can use the `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, and `(/=) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` function with expressions of type `a`. Here however you only use `Int`s, so we know for sure that we can do that.

Although from a theoretical perspective, it would not be *wrong* to write `Eq Int`, it is rather "non-sensical".